# How do I test a ViewModel class which has an interface dependecy that is generated by android as a Unit Test

Tags: android, mvvm, junit4, android-viewmodel

Good day all, am trying to test my ViewModel class and it has a dependency of datasource, I tried to mock this, but it won't work because it's an interface, I believe the interface implementation is generated at runtime, how do I unit test this class, below is my ViewModel class

```
class LoginViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
                                                 private val networkApi: NetworkAPI,
                                                 private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>)
   : ViewModel() {


   val clientNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val clientPassword = MutableLiveData<String>()

   private val _shouldNavigate = MutableLiveData(false)
   val shouldNavigate: LiveData<Boolean>
       get() = _shouldNavigate

   private val _errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val errorMessage: LiveData<String>
       get() = _errorMessage

private val _activateDeviceButton = MutableLiveData(false)
   val activateButton : LiveData<Boolean>
   get() = _activateDeviceButton

   init {
       populateApiWithFakeData()
   }


   suspend fun authenticateUsers(): Boolean {
       val clientNumber = clientNumber.value
       val clientPassword = clientPassword.value
       requireNotNull(clientNumber)
       requireNotNull(clientPassword)
       val (userExist, token) = networkApi.doesUserExist(clientNumber.toLong(), clientPassword)
       if (token.isNotBlank()) storeTokenInStore(token)
       return if (userExist) {
           true
       } else {
           _errorMessage.value = "Incorrect account details. Please try again with correct details"
           false
       }
   }

  private suspend fun storeTokenInStore(token: String) {
       dataStore.edit { pref ->
           pref[TOKEN_PREFERENCE] = token
       }
   }
```

and here is my ViewModel Test class

```
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginViewModelTest{


    private val context : Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    private val dataCentre = NetworkApImpl()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>

    @Before
    fun setUpDataCenters(){
        val loginData = DataFactory.generateLoginData()
        for (data in loginData){
            dataCentre.saveUserData(data)
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDownDataCenter(){
        dataCentre.clearDataSet()
    }

    @Test
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun authenticateUser_shouldAuthenticateUsers(){
        //Given
        val viewModel = LoginViewModel(context, dataCentre, dataStore)
        viewModel.clientNumber.value = "8055675745"
        viewModel.clientPassword.value = "robin"
        //When
        var result : Boolean? = null
        runBlocking {
            result = viewModel.authenticateUsers()
        }
        //Then
        Truth.assertThat(result).isTrue()
    }
```

Any assistance rendered will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply use context and instantiate datastore instead of mocking? val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = context.createDataStore(
  name = "whatever"
)

Comment: Yea. I tried that but my test went into a loop, it kept running and rolling till I had to stop it, my guess is to create a datastore you might need android resources, which is not available in a test enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your dependency in a class you own as Mockito suggests [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests). This also has the upside of letting you change your storage implementation latter without having and impact on every view model using it.

Comment: This makes sense, create an interface and create classes to implement the interface, one fake, one concrete implementation, swap in fake in the test, concrete implementation in main code, This should work. Thanks